# Chemically induced fear

Tags: science-based, torture

Secret police in my world want to interrogate subjects but they're very resistant to all techniques.So they want to induce fear in subjects.How they could achive this?

Comment: To quote some novel I read years ago: "The composition is classified. You don't expect me to release information to a subject, do you?"

Comment: Hello and Welcome to worldbuilding. As far as I can tell, this question is going to be more story based than it is worldbuilding. What your subjects fear is going to be entirely dependent on what you want them to fear and what your story dictates is necessary. This could be via a chemical. It could be via illusions, or torture or threatening their families. For example in 1984 it was rats eating your face off while you are alive. Pretty horrifying if you think about it. You can also look into the scarecrow from batman. Either way, the breaking point is up to you and what you deem necessary.

Comment: Are the subjects human?

Comment: FYI, agents can be trained to resist the truth serum or other chemicals. That's why some agencies keep investigating or allowed physical techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Like Scarecrow from Batman. Try to read about it, you may find something relevant.

Meanwhile, [refer to this](https://www.quora.com/Is-Scarecrows-fear-toxin-possible), Here you will find your answers.

Following is an answer from the link:

> Using a mixture that consisted of dopamine, yohimine, carbogen, 3-quinuclidinyl benzilate, L-34-dihydroxyphenylalanine, and corticotropin, I could stimulate a fearful response in both humans and animals.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a wild shot and somehow create [Norepinephrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norepinephrine) and then torture the victim. If the victim's hormonal system that transmits the "fight or flight" response is overloaded, and receives large fear stimuli, their fear learning will be multiplied. This will not, however, make him fearful by default, just extremely agitated. He needs external stimuli for the fear to be triggered, if I am to understand the texts correctly.

However, if the victim finds themselves in a torture situation, that shouldn't be hard, now, would it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for norepinephrine to target NMDA though.

Comment: You are absolutely correct :) I'll edit it accordingly.